# inconsistent behavior of json.Unmarshal into a map with custom types vs into a struct or slice

Tags: go, enums, maps, unmarshalling

I have a custom type, which is supposed to be an enumerator, and it implements json.Unmarshaler.

When I unmarshal into a **slice**, or a **struct** of this type, it works, like https://go.dev/play/p/DGg3nzo_VwN

When I unmarshal into a **map** containing this type, it breaks, like https://go.dev/play/p/YGgnRvr0agz

Crawling through the source code (go 1.18), I know how to make it work, just implement `encoding.TextUnmarshaler`, like https://go.dev/play/p/vY4E4snAY52 and I also have learned how the code works for maps: it checks if `encoding.TextUnmarshaler` is implemented, if yes, call its `UnmarshalJSON` before trying `UnmarshalText`. In other words, `UnmarshalText` must be present, however it will be ignored if `UnmarshalJSON` is also present.

Why is this precedence? Why only maps are treated this way?

Comment: Since json keys must be strings, I don't think there was ever a reason to handle other types. I think if you want generalized special handling of the map key types, then you must implement that at the map level, since the key type is part of the overall map type.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Jim, I think I understand why the key must implement TextUnmarshaler now, but why should “UnmarshalJSON” take precedence?

Answer (score 1):

From Go's [decoder](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/032678e0fb/src/encoding/json/decode.go#630):

```golang
// Map key must either have string kind, have an integer kind,
// or be an encoding.TextUnmarshaler.
```

So you must implement TextUnmarshaller.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  think I understand why the key must implement TextUnmarshaler now, but why should “UnmarshalJSON” take precedence?

Comment: This is done on purpose: you are unmarshalling a json that has strings as both key and values. However, you want to unmarshal this JSON onto a map[DataType]string. If you do not implement TextUnmarshaler on DataType, go is going to attempt to use the [default](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3/src/encoding/json/decode.go#797) unmarshal method for integer keys: `n, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64)`.

Comment: I do agree, however, that reading `To unmarshal a JSON object into a map, Unmarshal first establishes a map to use. If the map is nil, Unmarshal allocates a new map. Otherwise Unmarshal reuses the existing map, keeping existing entries. Unmarshal then stores key-value pairs from the JSON object into the map. The map's key type must either be any string type, an integer, implement json.Unmarshaler, or implement encoding.TextUnmarshaler.`is confusing at best, as this is really not what is happening :/

Comment: If you implement UnmarshalJSON on a custom type representing the map you want to deserialize the JSON to, you can avoid having to implement TextUnmarshaller: https://go.dev/play/p/6Mz7QfDSgGx

Comment: thank you very much @ebarti, that's helpful and interesting, although it might not suit me well (I might have multiple maps involving this type, wouldn't want to implement each one of them :))